# How to enable all exceptions for a specific javascript file?

Tags: debugging, exception, safari

I know how to enable all exceptions in the Safari debugger. But how do I enable exceptions for a certain javascript file?

So that the debugger will not break on all exceptions but on all exceptions within that specific javascript file.

Is there some filter that I can apply?

Comment: please upvote my question :D, then at least I will have enough reputation to vote on other things. Or shall I ask more questions :P